# Client Threatening to Contact Permanent Employer?

Tags: communication

I picked up a side job.  Terms were agreed on.  Payment up front and percentage of profits.

No money has been paid up front.  Communication has been tenuous.  I received a text message stating "I am beginning to get concerned about you, I'm going to have to track you down through your job".

The only attempts at communication from their end has been during my normal work hours (I don't answer the phone at work).  And no answer when I try to contact them back.  No response to my emails.

Ethically I feel I accepted this job I should see it through.  But a part of me doesn't respond well to threats and says I should tell them to kick rocks.  Any outside input?  Anyone have to deal with a situation like this?

Like I said, I have received no compensation yet, so part of me feels like I owe the client nothing more than to fire them.  I'm big on communication and shooting someone straight, and I feel like I deserve the same accommodations.

Comment: Does your full time employment contract allow work on the side?

Comment: Yes.  But I don't agree with the idea of a side job client attempting to use my full time employer as a threat.  It just reeks of shadyness

Comment: Since you haven't done any work for them, even if they come see you at work, mention you have done no work for them, and received no compensation anyways.

Comment: "Payment up front" means "I don't start work until I get paid" The fact that he hasn't paid you yet is a HUGE red flag. Fire this client. It's not worth the hassle.

Comment: They are not your client, and you have not picked up a side job - "Terms were agreed on. Payment up front", so before the payment has happened because of their fault, they're not a paying customer, you have no job, and no obligations to them.

Comment: Were appropriate times for communication discussed? Did you explain you are not available 9am-5pm weekdays? Don't get me wrong, I'd *immediately* drop them based on your second paragraph. I'm just curious if they knew correct times to communicate.

Comment: Yes, they know I will not answer the phone during my normal business hours.  I let everyone I know, whether it's a personal or professional relationship, that I will not answer the phone during business hours, and if I do answer the phone and it's not a life or death emergency then they will be put on auto reject forever and ever, amen.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would drop them asap. Their behavior is not magically going to change in the future as the contract goes on. Their threats are not an acceptable way to conduct business at all and if they threaten you now even when no money has exchanged hands, how much more so will they when there is money on the line.

I would walk away and not conduct business with them further.

Comment: Thank you.  I feel that is probably the best path as well, but really needed an outside view.

Comment: I agree. Since you did not do anything which your current employes does not allow, his threats are simply obnoxious. Ditch them in a polite manner letting them know that you are ditching them because of their conduct which is obnoxious.

Answer (score 10):

I'd send them an email with something along the lines of:

You can reach me by email at X, or by phone between the hours of Y and Z.   If this is not satisfactory, then I will not be able to do business with you.

And possibly add that section on acceptable communication methods/times to any future contracts you do on the side.